# creating kafka topics using ansible looping

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible

i try to create kafka topics by using ansible playbook to loop the below variables in group_var like the below

```
alltopics:
- topicname: abc1
    replication: 3
    partitions : 3
- topicname: xyx
    replication: 3
    partitions : 3
- topicname: qwe
    replication: 3
    partitions : 3
```

i have sheel task like this

```
- name: create topic
  shell: kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic abc
```

i couldnt create good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you should fix the indentation of your YAML to make it valid:

```yaml
alltopics:
  - topicname: abc1
    replication: 3
    partitions: 3
  - topicname: xyx
    replication: 3
    partitions: 3
  - topicname: qwe
    replication: 3
    partitions: 3
```

Then, in your task, you should use a loop to [iterate over a list of hashes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-list-of-hashes) (I used [multiline YAML](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) formatting for better readability):

```yaml
    - name: Create Kafka topics
      shell: >
        kafka-topics.sh
          --create
          --zookeeper localhost:2181
          --replication-factor {{ item.replication }}
          --partitions {{ item.partitions }}
          --topic {{ item.topicname }}
      loop: "{{ alltopics }}"
```

If you're working on a real-world application, I'd recommend to consider using existing tooling such as [ansible-kafka-admin](https://github.com/StephenSorriaux/ansible-kafka-admin).

Comment: Note: Zookeeper flag is deprecated. Should also add `--if-not-exists`